# iOS OpenGL too slow

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es

I'm new to Xcode programming and I'm trying to create an iPhone game using OpenGL with support for retina display at 60 FPS, but it runs way too slow. I based it on the GLSprite example at developer.apple. I've already optimized it the best I could, but it keeps running < 30 FPS on the Simulator (I haven't tested it on a real device yet - maybe it's faster?). The bottleneck appears to be drawing the polygons - I've used really small textures (256x256 PNG) and pixel formats (RGBA4444); I've disabled blending; I've moved all transformation code to the load phase hoping for better performance; everything to no success. I'm keeping a vertex array that stores everything for that step, then draws using GL_TRIANGLES with one function call - because I think it's faster than calling multiple glDrawArrays. It starts lagging when I reach about 120 vertexes (6 for each rectangular sprite), but in many places I've read the iPhone can handle even millions of vertexes. What's wrong with the code below? Is OpenGL the fastest way to render graphics on the iPhone? If not, what else should I use?

OpenGL loading code, called just once, at the beginning:

```
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]); //Binds a texture loaded previously with the code given below

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes); //The array holding the vertexes
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvCoord); //The array holding the uv coordinates
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

The texture loading method:

```
- (void)loadSprite:(NSString*)filename intoPos:(int)pos { //Loads a texture within the bundle, at the given position in an array storing all textures (but I actually just use one at a time)
CGImageRef spriteImage;
CGContextRef spriteContext;
GLubyte *spriteData;
size_t  width, height;

// Sets up matrices and transforms for OpenGL ES
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

// Clears the view with black
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// Sets up pointers and enables states needed for using vertex arrays and textures
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, spriteVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, spriteTexcoords);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

// Creates a Core Graphics image from an image file
spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:filename].CGImage;
// Get the width and height of the image
width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);
textureWidth[pos]=width;
textureHeight[pos]=height;
NSLog(@"Width %lu; Height %lu",width,height);
// Texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If you write an application that allows users to supply an image,
// you'll want to add code that checks the dimensions and takes appropriate action if they are not a power of 2.

if(spriteImage) {
    // Allocated memory needed for the bitmap context
    spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    // Uses the bitmap creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework. 
    spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    // After you create the context, you can draw the sprite image to the context.
    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), spriteImage);
    // You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.
    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

    // Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[pos]);
    // Bind the texture name.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[pos]);
    curTexture=pos;

    if (1) { //This should convert pixel format
        NSLog(@"convert to 4444");
        void*                   tempData;
        unsigned int*           inPixel32;
        unsigned short*         outPixel16;

        tempData = malloc(height * width * 2);

        inPixel32 = (unsigned int*)spriteData;
        outPixel16 = (unsigned short*)tempData;
        NSUInteger i;
        for(i = 0; i < width * height; ++i, ++inPixel32)
            *outPixel16++ = ((((*inPixel32 >> 0) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 12) | ((((*inPixel32 >> 8) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 8) | ((((*inPixel32 >> 16) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 4) | ((((*inPixel32 >> 24) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 0);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, tempData);
        free(tempData);
    } else {

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);           
    }

    // Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
    //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);
    // Release the image data
    free(spriteData);

    // Enable use of the texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // Set a blending function to use
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    // Enable blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

The actual drawing code that is called every game loop:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexIndex); //vertexIndex is the maximum number of vertexes at this loop

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the slowdowns are? If not, you should run Instruments and do a time sample to see where exactly your code is spending most of its time. That will tell you what you need to work on optimizing. OpenGL should be just fine for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [OpenGL programming guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) :

> **Important** Rendering performance of OpenGL ES in Simulator has no relation to the performance of OpenGL ES on an actual device.
>   Simulator provides an optimized software rasterizer that takes
>   advantage of the vector processing capabilities of your Macintosh
>   computer. As a result, your OpenGL ES code may run faster or slower in
>   iOS simulator (depending on your computer and what you are drawing)
>   than on an actual device. Always profile and optimize your drawing
>   code on a real device and never assume that Simulator reflects
>   real-world performance.

The simulator is not reliable to profile performance of OpenGL applications. You'll need to run/profile on the real hardware.

> It starts lagging when I reach about 120 vertexes (6 for each
>   rectangular sprite), but in many places I've read the iPhone can
>   handle even millions of vertexes.

To elaborate a bit on this comment of yours : the number of vertices is not the only variable impacting OpenGL performance.For example, with only a single triangle (3 vertices), you can draw pixels on the whole screen. This obviously needs more computation than drawing a small triangle covering only a few pixels. The metric representing the capacity of drawing many pixels is known as *fill-rate*.

If your vertices represent large triangles on screen, it is probable that fill-rate is your performance bottleneck, and not vertex transform. As the iOS simulator does use a software rasterizer, albeit being optimized, it is probably slower that actual specialized hardware.

You should profile your application to know what is your actual performance bottleneck before optimizing ; [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH105) can help you.

Comment: Well, but I thought even Simulator could handle that few vertexes, so I assumed my coding had to be the problem...

Comment: The emulator is known for being slow, and actually may not always support all of the OpenGL ES calls you are making due to version incompatibility.

Comment: @HLorenzi updated my answer to elaborate on your comment about vertex  count.

Comment: +1 for correct answer - the simulator actually emulates the device GL using a solution that is entirely done in software. The results are hardly ever close to what you see on the actual device.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll look into it. But, as you noted, the problem should be this software/hardware rasterizer difference, so I'll wait for when I get the chance to test on a real device.

Comment: Software rasterizer in simulator is very different from actual hardware, even if compared with oldest MBX-based devices. It has somewhat different feature set, limitations and performance. It doesn't support some features from "real" hardware and supports some features that hardware doesn't. When doing anything non-trivial, you shouldn't waste your time to figure out simulator quirks.